# Setting a Coupon for Discount Shipping Rates in Magento

Tags: magento

I need to Set free Shipping on orders over $25.00 for continental US. But for Alaska and Hawaii and PR. I need this to be a 50% Discount off Shipping only.

The Free Shipping is no problem, the 50% off shipping costs seems to be the issue.

We don't mind doing this via code or through Admin. Any tips would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Check under promotion -> shopping cart price rules -> and add the condition based on shipping region or state (whatever fits your needs) and another one based on amount of the order. In the tab actions you're able to set free shipping and such.

Comment: that is good.. but i want to Discount the Shipping to outside the 48 states to 50 % off Shipping only. The discount for 50% off using the regions will apply the discount to the product and the shipping.